# Bootstrap breakpoints seemingly inaccurate on mobile check?

Tags: html

I'm trying to learn the basics of the bootstrap grid system, however whenever I'm testing the basic grid system from my Iphone, the 3 columns are still displayed in one row and are not changed into individual rows. From my understanding, the col-sm-4 divs should be displayed as 1/3 of the container size for all devices above 576px. When I test my website on my 1920x1080 monitor, it appears the breakpoints are working correctly when I shrink and grow the browser window however when I load the web page from my Iphone (a device which I believe should be below the col-sm breakpoint) The columns are still displayed in one row. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the code.

```
<!doctype=html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/CSS/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>About Me</h3>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Why Web Development?</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Lorem </h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After further testing, I've found that my phone is being considered a medium sized device (affected by anything using col-md or above breakpoints) even though it's a normal sized Iphone 8. Is this normal?

Comment: Apple iPhone 8 has viewport size 375 x 667 Pixels and its pixel ratio is about 2. Its size should help guide you on which bootstrap layout values to use.

Comment: Also, if you want to know the exact dimensions of your viewport you can see [here](https://viewportsizer.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem was not because of CSS styling or anything bootstrap specific, but the one important thing I forgot to add to my HTML code was defining the viewport meta tag. I assume bootstrap uses this to help with breakpoints. Make sure you include the tag!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple breakpoints to take care of each viewport size. For example:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xm-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xm-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        
    </div>
    <div class="col-xm-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use media queries to specify the exact layout you'd want:

`index.html`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>About Me</h3>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Why Web Development?</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Lorem </h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`styles.css`

```css
/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/* On screens that are 992px wide or less, go from four columns to two columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

If you would like to be more specific on the type of viewport you are targeting (here I am considering iPhone 8), you can do:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 767px) { 
/* Your column styles... */ 
}
```

Comment: The documentation states that col-xm is no longer in use in bootstrap v4 as it is now considered the default, another answer has pointed to the same kind of idea with specific breakpoint column sizes but neither have worked as of yet. Any other ideas would be appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using a mobile first approach, the solution should work. What you should do is adjust the value of `col-sm` accordingly. For example, `col-sm-12` will make each column to fill an entire viewport in smaller devices. If you do `col-sm-4`, this will create 4 columns in the smaller viewports. So, work with grid layout numbers in the classes.

Comment: @JackEcuyer share your output from your trial so I can help you further

Comment: `col-sm-4` creates 3 columns in smaller viewports.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use media queries as seen in the edit

Comment: I've done a test by creating a new html file with just bootstrap links no css styling and a layout of 3 divs with the classes col-12 and col-md-4 which as per the documentation should filter into 3 rows after the medium device breakpoint. However when I test this with the inspect element tool the page still stays as one row on all small device options (iphones galaxy etc.). The only way I can make it change to one row is using The window resizer chrome extension and choosing the iphone 5 or 6 options. Very odd, any advice?

Comment: Update: I've experimented with this more and ive come to the conclusion that Iphone 8 must be past the medium breakpoint. The only way i can get the page to be responsive is using col-12 col-lg-4.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4"> #I have changed the classes here.
      <h3>About Me</h3>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-4"> #I have changed the classes here.
      <h3>Why Web Development?</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-4"> #I have changed the classes here.
      <h3>Lorem </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

- col-12 class gets applied to all the breakpoints
- Adding col-md-4 make the mobile scale devices to have col-12 but medium and large scale will have col-md-4 grid.
- Furthur more if you want to change the column grid for large scale you can also add col-lg-6. Now this will make col-12 for small scale. col-md-4 for medium scale and col-lg-6 for large scale devices. Always go from smaller breakpoints to larger breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've changed the classes for each div to use this method however the page is still displaying as one row on iphone. The only way I've been able to get the page to display as multiple rows on iphone is by changing the div class to col-lg or above breakpoints. I don't want to use this fix though because it doesn't follow the documented breakpoint width rules and I feel like it will affect my understanding later down the line. Another other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually working as you already specified the width to be `col-sm-4` which is working as intended. But the reason why it is not working for you appears to be you may have added margin or changed the value of the CSS file.

Note that the divs are getting a `width:100%` from `0px` to `575px` and when the width is `576px` the `col-sm-4` will kick in and work as it should.

So I would say the problem is from your custom CSS to prove it just make a new project and get the same code you posted and just add the bootstrap CDN and everything should work.

In order for us to help you find out the actual cause of this issue, we need you to add the CSS code you wrote.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll make a project with no custom CSS later and test it.

Comment: I've done a test by creating a new html file with just bootstrap links no css styling and a layout of 3 divs with the classes col-12 and col-md-4 which as per the documentation should filter into 3 rows after the medium device breakpoint. However when I test this with the inspect element tool the page still stays as one row on all small device options (iphones galaxy etc.). The only way I can make it change to one row is using The window resizer chrome extension and choosing the iphone 5 or 6 options. Very odd, any advice?

Comment: Update: I've experimented with this more and ive come to the conclusion that Iphone 8 must be past the medium breakpoint. The only way i can get the page to be responsive is using col-12 col-lg-4.

Comment: No, actually the `md` breakpoint should be for tablet devices. You really have some sort of issue in the design I assume.